# Finding advanced option details for a windows shortcut

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I'm trying to use group policy to replace the default windows Powershell shortcut with one that automatically checks the advanced option for the default shortcut: 'Run as Administrator' that can be found when editing the properties of the shortcut. Shown as followed, [image: Powershell shortcut advanced options.]

However in group policy, the settings for shortcuts are limited. You may provide arguments, but that is all. and I suspect that it is an argument in the default shortcut that allows it to run as Administrator because besides giving arguments and a starting directory to a shell there is nothing else to it besides the shell. (See picture)
[image: Group policy shortcut options]

Unfortunately, windows does not show what arguments are provided to the default shortcut that allow it run as administrator.
[image: Shortcut details]

So if someone could tell me what arguments the shortcut has that allow it to do 'Run as Administrator' I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, this is defined by byte #21 in the saved shortcut file.. If the value of that byte is 0x22, the `Run as Administrator` is set. You could use my function [New-Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547816/9898643) to achieve that

Comment: @Theo actually it's not. See **[MS-SHLLINK]-170915.pdf** at page 13, there is only 1 bit responsible to this.

Comment: @filimonic You're right. I have edited [my function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547816/9898643)

Answer (score 0):

There is unsupported usy-at-your-own-risk method - [setting byte #21 to 34](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958432/1936966)

There is also more argumented method [doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002207/1936966) ( I think it is better, because it takes into account old binary value )

Alternatively, to use from PowerShell you should find a wrapper around WinApi methods to set SLDF_RUNAS_USER flag for shortcut.

I think, you should test second method to use in PowerShell

There is no *native* way doing this from any .net-based language.

Documentation: [MS-SHLLINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink)