# PowerShell command to set Visual Studio to Run as Administrator

Tags: powershell

I have been assigned the job of automating a long list of tasks for developers to load into Intune.
One of the tasks is to set the Run As Administrator feature to Visual Studio with a script.
I know you can right-click on the exe, go to properties > Advanced and set that setting, but I'm struggling to find a scriptable way to do that. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: This to update the shortcut to send the command to run as administrator.

Comment: Remember the SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: What did you search for? What have you tried? What were the results/errors? Show some stuff. **Also of note, this is not the first time this question has been asked.** Several articles exist on the topic. Lastly, it's a choice but, as an operational risk and end-user delivery thing, developers should not be running/developing as admin anyway. They should be doing that as a regular user, and only elevate to admin for dev admin-required tasks.

Comment: You can just create a reference machine, set whatever you want and export /backup the settings -- shortcuts, and import/install them to a new machine. Just as you would when creating a normal Gold OS reference image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997799/how-to-create-a-run-as-administrator-shortcut-using-powershell and here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d97ae6ae-9d34-4e78-b8ca-c7a7f31ac80c/modify-shortcuts-advanced-properties-with-powershell

Answer (score 1):

The [shell-friendly way to create shortcut files (`*.lnk`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508759/45375) unfortunately does *not* provide a way to mark a shortcut file as needing to run *with elevation* (as administrator).

To do so, you have two options:

- A **quick-and-dirty solution** based on *raw byte manipulation* of a `.lnk` file.

  - The **caveat** is that such an approach may *break* in a future Windows version, should the binary file format of shortcut file changes. See below.
- A  **proper solution via the appropriate COM interfaces**, which are **not script-friendly**, however.

  - See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071219-00/?p=24103) for C++ sample code.

---

**Quick-and-dirty solution**, effective as of Windows 10, gratefully adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958432/45375):

```
# Get the *full path* of the target shortcut file (*.lnk),
# using sample path ~/Desktop/test.lnk here.
$shortcutFile = Convert-Path -LiteralPath (Get-Item ~/Desktop/test.lnk)

# Read the shortcut file's raw byte contents.
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($shortcutFile)

# Set the relevant byte to mark the shortcut as needing to
# run with elevation.
$bytes[21] = 34

# Save the modified byte array back to the original file.
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($shortCutLocation, $bytes)
```